# Recalling the 'onInit()'

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, voice-recognition, google-text-to-speech

In Android Text To speech using Google engine, you can't change the language without re-calling the 'onInit()' method. How can I recall this method, without restarting the application?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart the 'application', you could just `shutdown()` the current TTS object and initialise a new one. That would then call `onInit()`.

However, you don't need to do this to change the language, you can do this at any time by calling `mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN)` If you kept a reference to the original language before the switch, you can then just switch back once the utterance is completed.